# Graph analysis and phenomenon modeled by the curve $S(t)= 1/(1+e^{-t})$

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematical-modeling

So the question is:

[image]

The graph looks like:

[image]

So where I stand with this question is that I am struggling to find something that it models. Once I find some phenomenon that it looks similar to, I should be able to explain the graph a bit better.

Anyone have any advice for where to look for some phenomenon that could be modeled by the curve?

Comment: Maybe what the person who posed the question is looking for is that for $x>0$ the function quickly approximates $1$, while for $x<0$ the function quickly approximates $0$. In other words it approximates the step function which can model many things, *e.g.*, a switch!

Comment: Hmmm, that's a good thought. I had considered the step function, but thought it was too simple of an answer. But with some more consideration, it might be exactly what they are looking for.

Comment: According to wikipedia (See [logistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) or [sigmoid ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)function), it is used among other things, to model learning curves of systems or population growth. Although don't rush to dismiss a simple answer! This function with additional parameters can be also used in decision systems (given an input $x$, output a yes (1) or no (0) answer).